how to update RequestBody in Karate where variables have '-'
Update RequestBody in Karate where variables have '-'
Request Body:
{
    "otp": "520496",
    "headers": {
        "X-lover-Merchant-Id": "7KY64KPS9MC25"
    }
}

Feature file
Scenario: Validate the OTP for changing owner mobile number in case MFA is OFF.
    * def requestBody = read('classpath:api-tests/mss/fixtures/request/validateOTP.json')
    * print merchantId
    * requestBody.headers.X-lover-Merchant-Id = merchantId
    And print requestBody
    And path '/non-mfa/otp'
    * header Cookie = cookieSession
    And request requestBody
    When method PUT
    Then status 400

Getting result as below:
01: requestBody.headers.X-lover-Merchant-Id = merchantId
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:37 Invalid left hand side for assignment
requestBody.headers.X-lover-Merchant-Id = merchantId

